# Condition based class in knockoutjs data binding

Tags: css, knockout.js

Condition based class in knockoutjs data binding.

Request you please point out where I'm wrong

```js
function blahBlah() {
  var self = this;
  self.isColorRed = ko.observable(true);
}
ko.applyBindings(new blahBlah());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.colorRed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>Green everywhere</div>
<div class="colorRed">RED without Bind</div>
<div data-bind="class: {colorRed:isColorRed}">Should be red</div> <!-- not working -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `isColorRed` as a function, also use the `css` keyword

```js
function blahBlah() {
  var self = this;
  self.isColorRed = ko.observable(true);
}
ko.applyBindings(new blahBlah());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.colorRed {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>Green everywhere</div>
<div class="colorRed">RED without Bind</div>
<div data-bind="css: { colorRed: isColorRed() }">Should be red</div>
```

Comment: It worked, could you please tell how to use `number` observable, like `self.conditionalColor = ko.obserable(2);` and `data-bind="css: { colorBlue: conditionalColor === 2 }"` [jsFiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/dchennaraidu/bn7uxke5/4)

Comment: Your fiddle is correct, just a typo of `ko.obserable(2)` Change it to `ko.observable(2)`